# Cumulative sum grouping by date and user columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, cumulative-sum

I currently have a mysql table that looks like the following:

```
+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|      datetime       | name | flag1 | flag2 | flag3 |
+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2018-05-06 00:00:05 | john |     0 |     2 |     1 |
| 2018-05-06 00:00:10 | john |     1 |     0 |     1 |
| 2018-05-06 00:00:15 | john |     1 |     1 |     1 |
| 2018-05-06 00:00:05 | troy |     1 |     1 |     1 |
| 2018-05-06 00:00:10 | troy |     1 |     1 |     1 |
| 2018-05-06 00:00:15 | troy |     1 |     0 |     1 |
| 2018-05-05 00:00:05 | john |     1 |     0 |     0 |
| 2018-05-05 00:00:10 | john |     1 |     1 |     0 |
| 2018-05-05 00:00:15 | john |     0 |     1 |     0 |
| 2018-05-05 00:00:05 | troy |     2 |     1 |     1 |
| 2018-05-05 00:00:10 | troy |     3 |     1 |     0 |
| 2018-05-05 00:00:15 | troy |     3 |     1 |     3 |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:05 | john |     1 |     1 |     1 |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:10 | john |     1 |     1 |     1 |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:15 | john |     0 |     0 |     2 |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:05 | troy |     3 |     1 |     0 |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:10 | troy |     1 |     1 |     1 |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:15 | troy |     1 |     1 |     1 |
+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I am wanting to consolidate it down into the cumulative of each of the flag values for each individual **name** on each unique day.

I am trying to consolidate it down into this:

```
+------------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    date    | name | total_flag1 | total_flag2 | total_flag3 |
+------------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2018-05-06 | john |           2 |           3 |           3 |
| 2018-05-06 | troy |           3 |           2 |           3 |
| 2018-05-05 | john |           2 |           2 |           0 |
| 2018-05-05 | troy |           8 |           3 |           4 |
| 2018-05-04 | john |           2 |           2 |           4 |
| 2018-05-04 | troy |           5 |           3 |           2 |
+------------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The actual table I am dealing with contains 300+ unique names, with 288 (5 minute intervals throughout the day) rows for each containing flag values for each time.

I know I can do this for each individual date/name by doing something along the lines of the following:

```
@flag1Cuml := 0;
@flag2Cuml := 0;
@flag2Cuml := 0;

SELECT  
    DATE(datetime) as date,
    name,
    (@flag1Cuml  := @flag1Cuml  + flag1) as total_flag1,
    (@flag2Cuml  := @flag2Cuml  + flag2) as total_flag2,
    (@flag2Cuml  := @flag2Cuml  + flag3) as total_flag3
WHERE 
    name = 'John'
    AND DATE(datetime) = '2018-05-06'
```

Obviously this is not optimal in the slightest since my table is so big. I am sure it is possible to do this all in one nested query but I am new to mysql and am unsure how to get what I am needing.

Ideally I would like to use this query to generate a new view given it's possible.

Comment: Your expected output is simple, it's not a cumulative sum as your mentioned in the question title, I think you are expecting cumulative sum

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything cumulative about the numbers.  I see a simple `group by`:

```
select date(datetime) as date, name, sum(flag1) as flag1,
       sum(flag2) as flag2, sum(flag3) as flag3
from t
group by date(datetime), name;
```

Comment: I may have been over-complicating this all along.